# Python unittest - Extra Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Here is my test script:

```
# tests/runner.py
import unittest

# import your test modules
import TC110
import TC112

# initialize the test suite
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite  = unittest.TestSuite()

# add tests to the test suite
suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(TC110))
suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(TC112))

# initialize a runner, pass it your suite and run it
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3)
result = runner.run(suite)
```

I have TC110.py and TC112.py in the same directory and am running my test like this,

```
"python -m unittest runner"
```

I am getting output like this,

```
test_ldap_login (TC110.TestTC110) ... ok
test_download_artifact (TC112.TestTC112) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 1.929s

OK

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why I am getting "Ran 0 tests", how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an extra "Ran 0 tests" for essentially the same reason that `print(print("asdf"))` prints an extra `None`: you're issuing two testing commands.

Your `runner.py` script loads tests from other files and runs them. If you had simply told Python to run the script (`python runner.py`), you wouldn't have gotten the spurious extra output.

Instead of telling Python to run the script, you have told the unittest module to load and run all tests from `runner.py`. As a side effect, this runs the body of `runner.py`, running the tests you wanted. `unittest` then loads and runs all 0 tests contained in `runner.py`, because you told it to.

Comment: how can i make my script to work with "python -m unittest"? this is the requirement for different reason...